# On iPhone X can you see the most recent running apps?

Tags: iphone, ios

On iPhone 7 it is possible to double tap the Home button to see them. On iPhone X is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swipe up from the bottom of the screen and hold for a moment, you will see the most recent applications. You can then swipe left and right to select.

Comment: that's interesting... it seems like (1) swipe up from bottom ≡ pressing the Home button, and (2) swipe up from bottom and hold ≡ double tap on the Home button